# Inconsistent variable output

Tags: javascript, jquery

A few days ago I made a lord generator for a game called Broken History I play with my mates, I started the code myself but ended up getting help with the code to finish it.

I then set about making a char gen for the same game, using the exact same methods that worked before, everything was looking good every element did what it was supposed to. However, when I got the resulting text the first time the variable curFaction was called it read `undefined` the second time it read the faction the user chose in the select box i.e. `Saxathia`. The variable is assigned in the `$(document).ready()` function so in theory is should be assigned before it is called right?

I can't think why this happens, the variable is called as part of an array does that make any difference?

[image]

Here is the jsLint http://jsfiddle.net/CYe8J/31/

Comment: which line is the function to gen called?

Comment: what you suppose to ask. the jsFiddle working fine. Whats the problem is. can you point it out in jsfiddle

Comment: Try using firebug - watch the console and see if the underlying system is doing any unexpected requests behind the scenes - perhaps the game is making ajax requests that manipulate the value of this variable.

Comment: I use the built in developer tools with chrome, I ran it through jslint no problems other than the arrays not being literal (that was a warning not an error) It's just as RB said below the variable was being called before the user has set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting the character description string when the page is loaded, before the user has selected a faction.

```
// curFaction is undefined here, as user cannot select a faction 
// *before* the page is loaded!!
var aLevel[1] = "Description1 of guy from " + curFaction + ".";
```

The **quickest** fix is to generate the description as and when it is required. One way to do this would be to store a function in `aLevel`, rather than a string, like the following:

```
var aLevel[1] = function () { "Description1 of guy from " + curFaction + "."; };
var aLevel[2] = function () { "Description2 of guy from " + curFaction + "."; };
var aLevel[3] = function () { "Description3 of guy from " + curFaction + "."; };
```

Then, when you need your description, call the function:

```
// Original code:
"Stuff about claim on throne. " + aLevel[temp6] + ".";

// New code - note brackets after "aLevel[temp6]"
"Stuff about claim on throne. " + aLevel[temp6]() + ".";
```

I've [created a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJjxT/) showing this.

As an aside, your code could generally be refactored quite a lot - as a rule, if you find you are writing the same algorithm over and over again, then you need to remember the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) :)

Comment: Thanks :) It probably could be changed around quite a bit you're right but I've not had much experience in minimising code haha